# Special Input problems on competitive programming questions?

Tags: python, input

I am currently working on Constructing a Number on HackerRank (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/constructing-a-number/problem), and I have come across a certain type of input:

```
3
1
9
3
40 50 90
2
1 4
```

Apparently, there are 3 test cases inside those 7 lines of input. Can someone please explain why it's like that?

Comment: How do you know that these are 3 test cases?

Comment: The explanation can be found on the page linked, under "Input Format". In every HR problem I've tried, they always explain the format of the input in the body of the question.

Comment: Why is this surprising? The problem says “The first line contains a single integer  denoting the number of queries. The following lines describe the queries” so your input has three queries each two lines, i.e. a total of 7 lines.

Comment: @mkrieger1 They gave example output, and there were 3 individual outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the section [Input Format](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/constructing-a-number/problem#tab-2-content-undefined):

> The first line contains a single integer t denoting the number of queries. The following lines describe the queries. Each query is described in two lines. The first of these lines contains a single integer n. The second contains  space-separated integers a1, a2, ..., an.

Thus, the first number denotes how many queries you need to expect, but then there are the real queries as pairs of lines: first line in one pair has one integer, second line in the same pair has a list of integers. Such pairs just repeat. I believe you got confused by the fact that the length of the list of integers is not necessary constant.

In your example with comments:

```
3 // How many of the queries?

// 1st query:
1 // Integer
9 // List of integers

// 2nd query:
3 // Integer
40 50 90 // List of integers

// 3rd query:
2 // Integer
1 4 // List of integers
```